# Pull Files to Android Device do not shows on PC

Tags: c#, android, .net, io, adb

I am developing an application in C # that creates and sends an SQLite database for the device. I use the [Madbee library](http://madb.codeplex.com/) to send files to the device. It happens that the application sends the file without problems, even if we open the database on the device we see that the data is updated.
But when accessing the data of the device from the PC the file is not listed. It appears only after restarting the equipment.

I believe it is a bug or something WPD. I tried using the command "remount" adb, but was not successful.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

PC: Windows 7 Professional.
Device: Motorola Razor D3
Visual Studio 2010. +. NET Framework 4

Comment: Is it possible to show us some of your code for sending / accessing data?

Comment: I use the Madbee library this library encapsulate methods to send/receive files to Device. But I'm see if the problem is on Device. It's not rooted. In another devices works fine

Comment: 1) Where in device are you storing the files: in SD card? 2) How is the device mounted to the PC: via MTP?

Comment: Yes, I'm storing on the SD card, but the problem occurs meso I store in the internal memory of the device. The connection is made using the MTP with the device drivers installed on the PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem might be with MadBee library according to your statement.

First, "adb remount" will not help anything related with the internal SDCARD. This command only works for the debug-dev-devices, on which the ADB daemon is running in root user and thus could remount system partition from ro to rw.

Second, when you say that 'the app works well when send files to devices but cannot list the files on the device', I suppose that you are referring the problem happens when you are trying to perform r/w via MadBee library. So, please make sure by executing "adb shell ls -l /path/of/your/file" command to check if the file is OK. If the file is there, it is 99% that your library does not work correctly. If the file cannot be seen by adb shell, there are many potential reasons.

P.S. If I remember correctly, ADB shell does nothing to do with the "MTP" or "SDCARD" mode.

Comment: I suspected that too, but I tried with another dll that I found on the XDA Developers forum AndroidLib http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1512685
I tested with other equipment using the two alternatives and the two worked, apparently has something to do with the device not be root. I could use another device, but my client has this model, so I'm stuck with this. Even connecting to the debug mode the problem happens. I appreciate the attention.

Answer (score -2):

Very easy, try another device! Can be security options!

Comment: I could use another device, but my client has this model, so I'm stuck with this.